# Jest how to test error thrown in setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jestjs, settimeout

My code looks like this:

```
const myFunc =() =>{
    setTimeout(()=>throw new Error('err within setTimeout'),500);
}
```

How do I test in the Jest framework that the error is thrown?

Comment: I think your code has syntax error. At least for me this code shows error: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token throw`. I believe it should be `setTimeout(()=> {throw new Error('err within setTimeout')},500);`

Answer (score 1):

The only way I see is to mock `setTimeout` itself to make it run synchronously. `jest.useFakeTimers()` + `jest.runAllTimers()` can do that for you:

```
jest.useFakeTimers();

it("throws", () => {
  expect.assertions(1); // don't miss that to ensure exception has been thrown!
  myFunc();
  try {
    jest.runAllTimers();
  } catch(e) {
    expect(e.message).toEqual('err within setTimeout');
  }
});
```

Comment: I tried to do this, but no luck. The error seems to be thrown from the main loop scope

Comment: test above passed to me. Does your actual function look like you showed?